# How to create a function to calculate g(1,2) g(2,3) g(1,3) for equations like this g(1)+g(2)+g(1)*g(2)?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create Matlab code to calculate these following equations in Matlab

```
g(1,2)=g(1)+g(2)+g(1)g(2)

g(1,3)=g(1)+g(3)+g(1)g(3)

g(2,3)=g(2)+g(3)+g(2)g(3)
```

and values of g(1), g(2),g(3) are available.
 Where should I start to write such Matlab code?

Comment: Welcome on board Hossein, my Matlab times are too long ago to remember how to write a function. Nonetheless I'd like to point out that you'll probably get better answers if you format your questions more nicely, e.g. using code section etc. How to format on stack overflow can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: It is unclear what you exactly want to calculate. You show that you have a function `g` (same function, or three different ones?) which is dependent on two arguments, but in your equation they are only dependent on one argument. Please describe your problem more clearly.

Comment: I want to do this in Matlab

      g(1,2)=g(1)+g(2)+g(1)g(2)

     g(1,3)=g(1)+g(3)+g(1)g(3)

     g(2,3)=g(2)+g(3)+g(2)g(3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem here appears to be that you have functions of one and two variables, but you're calling them the same thing (`g`). Let's call the function of one variable `g` and the function of two variables (that you want to create) `f`. Assuming the function `g` already exists, you can create `f` using an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) like so:

```
f = @(x1, x2) g(x1)+g(x2)+g(x1)*g(x2);
```

And calling it like this:

```
result = f(1, 2);
```

is equivalent to:

```
result = g(1)+g(2)+g(1)*g(2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. How can I write some loop to calculate it by itself?
(to calculate f(1,2) f(2,3) f(1,3) automatically)

Comment: @HosseinDavallo: If it's just those 3 you have to calculate, why do you need a loop? Are you wanting to calculate this for a larger set of values?

Comment: Sorry. I'm just new to Matlab. I want to learn this for bigger sets and dimentions.

Comment: @HosseinDavallo: The documentation for [for loops](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html), along with the examples there, is the first place I would suggest starting.